# How can I run a MEmu android emulator in a VMware Windows 10 Virtual Machine?

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a MacBook Pro running bootcamp with windows 7 on it, and I am trying to run a MEmu android emulator on a VMware windows 10 VM (all inside my bootcamp partition). The reason for this is id like to have a sandbox keeping my data private and separate from my bootcamp partition while using the emulator.

MEmu downloads, and installs fine but then gets stuck at 99% infinitely while setting up the emulator. I have been searching the web for quite some time now looking for anything that might give me some insight on how to do this or why this isn't possible and have found nothing.

I have tried installing VMware tools to try and match the graphics requirements, and I have edited my VMs settings so that its configured to run with VT-x/AMD-V enabled. Is there any other way I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Wont work because memu is a virtual machine. Memu actually uses a hacked version of virtualbox.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can. Tested in VMware 17 on Windows 10.